# Codeigniter, using set_checkbox in a controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've got a loop that generates checkboxes, I have it working within the view, but I would like to move it into the controller and then pass the resulting string to the view. The problem is set_checkbox() doesn't seem to remember the values when it's placed in a controller. It does however seem to set the default value.

Edit: This is only an issue when validation fails and I want checkboxes to retain the users selections. Otherwise code is working as expected. I also have a validation rule set.

```
    $languages_by_name = $this->event_model->get_spoken_languages_by_name();

    // Generate array from model data for form_dropdown()
    $i = 1; 
    $list_languages = '';
    foreach ($languages_by_name as $row) {
        $i == 1 ? $first = TRUE : $first = FALSE; // Check if this is the first radio and precheck it.
        $list_languages .= '<label>' . form_checkbox('spokenLanguages[]', $row->event_spoken_id, set_checkbox('spokenLanguages', $row->event_spoken_id, $first)) . ' ' . $row->name . '</label> ';
        $i++;
    }
    // Pass $list_languages to view
    $this->data['list_languages'] = $list_languages;
```

Comment: `var_dump($list_languages)` might help a lot :)

Comment: How so? $list_languages is a bunch of checkboxes with the first one checked and working as expected but not remembering the checked values when form submission fails due to validation errors.

Comment: yo need to set new data to the ´$list_languages ´ via ´$this->input->post('spokenLanguages')´, please do var_dump as I asked and edit it in your question, also could you please post whole method in edit? (with validation included). thanks

Comment: Thanks, that got me looking in the right place. Code is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working code for the controller. There might be a more elegant way to do this.

```
    // Generate array from model data for form_dropdown()
    $i = 1; 
    $list_languages = '';
    foreach ($languages_by_name as $row) {
        // Check if there is post data
        if(!$this->input->post('spokenLanguages')) {
            // Set first element to checked
            $i == 1 ? $selection = TRUE : $selection = FALSE; // Check if this is the first radio and precheck it.
        } else {
            // Check if this input is checked
            if(in_array($row->event_spoken_id, $this->input->post('spokenLanguages'))) {
                $selection = TRUE;
            } else {
                $selection = FALSE;
            }   
        }

        $list_languages .= '<label>' . form_checkbox('spokenLanguages[]', $row->event_spoken_id, set_checkbox('spokenLanguages', $row->event_spoken_id, $selection)) . ' ' . $row->name . '</label> ';
        $i++;
    }
    // Pass $list_languages to view
    $this->data['list_languages'] = $list_languages;
```